# tns:Include error when trying to connect to SOAP web-service

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd

I have an external web-service: `http://188.254.16.92:7777/gateway/services/SID0003022?WSDL`
When I'm trying to connect to it (by the use of XML Spy or Informatica Powercenter), I receive an error:

```
File http://188.254.16.92:7777/gateway/services/SID0003022?WSDL is not valid.
    File http://188.254.16.92:7777/gateway/services/SID0003022/N1503900007/SID0003022/P48559386/OwsmImport.xsd is not valid.
        Invalid XML schema: ''tns:Include' is already declared in schema document 'http://188.254.16.92:7777/gateway/services/SID0003022/P1139237197/SID0003022/N1503900007/SID0003022/P48559386/OwsmImport.xsd'.'
            Error location: xs:schema / xs:element
```

As far  as I see there is no problem with xsd-schema.. I'm quite new to this topic so I apologize if the question is a stupid one.

Comment: I think you have more than one "tns:include"s in the file, don't know what it is. Try deleting one of them.

Comment: Ishmet thank you for your answer. I can't edit this web-service because it's not mine - i'm a consumer. The owner of web-service says that it functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the schema is referenced twice from different locations:

/N1503900007/SID0003022/P48559386/OwsmImport.xsd

and

/P1139237197/SID0003022/N1503900007/SID0003022/P48559386/OwsmImport.xsd

If that is the case then there is a problem with the service wsdl, although cannot confirm further without seeing wsdl.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hugh! 
You can see the WSDL here: http://188.254.16.92:7777/gateway/services/SID0003022?WSDL

Comment: I had tried already but I cannot resolve that address. Can you paste it into Gist or something? (http://gist.github.com/)